# Cannot make a str_replace() function to work properly when replacing a paragraph into a heading

Tags: php

I have a normal paragraph like this:

```
<p>Hey there, I'm a normal paragraph. generated by a Wordpress blog</p>
```

And I want to change the:

```
<p> with <h2> and </p> with </h2>
```

I used `str_replace();`

```
$paragraph = array("<p>", "</p>");
$heading2 = array("<h2>","</h2>");
$first_sentence = str_replace($paragraph, $heading2, $first_sentence);
```

And it should work, but I get this:

```
<h2>Hey there, I'm a normal paragraph. generated by a Wordpress blog<p>/p&gt;</p>
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: I am pretty sure the function is correct but I wanted to double check here because I am a newb:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regex for this kind of task:

```
$first_sentence = preg_replace('/<p>([^<]+)<\/p>/', '<h2>$1</h2>', $first_sentence);
```

`([^<]+)` means: catch all chars, until `<` occurs.

Here you can see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/FW1vm5

But if it gets more complex you should use other techniques (like a DOM parser)

Comment: Ty, clever :) Please tell me, how do I modify the preg_replace to work on the first set of <p></p> only. I would like to use this on a text with several paragraphs. Can it be done?

Comment: Yes, there's a 4th parameter `limit`, just set it to 1. (see [the docs](http://php.net/preg_replace))

Comment: Ty very much. Regular expressions are really useful; I'll start learning them.